# Convert into a simple sentence

Tags: sentence

The sentence is -

> They called their goodbyes and the train pulled out of the station.

The answer given in the book is -

> They having called their goodbyes, the train pulled out of the station.

Is it correct? I really doubt whether the book is correct.

Comment: Both sentences are unidiomatic (i.e. not something a native speaker would ever say). That said, I don't know what you mean by converting into a "simple sentence" (nor what you mean by "it really looks betwixt and between", either). You might prefer to ask such questions on our sister site, [ELL.SE].

Comment: umm, three kinds of sentences - simple, compound , complex. The sentence given is compound , and the instruction was to convert into a  simple sentence

Comment: @Dan I think "betwixt and between" is because one might expect a form "They, having called their goodbyes, did something else" rather than use *having* in the way it is here. If the suggested solution is correct at all, it's ***really, really archaic*** (that is, **firmly** entrenched in the 18th/19th centuries, rather than further back). I would suggest that the textbook be junked.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm with you on that.

Comment: I've edited the betwixt and between part

Comment: The book wants you to transform a sentence comprising two independent clauses joined by a conjunction into a single-clause sentence. As an intellectual exercise, why not? However, the resulting sentence uses a construction that fell into disuse several decades ago, and as well as being harder to get one's head around is actually less concise than the perfectly acceptable two-clause version.

Comment: @LachlanDominic I'm more worried about the precision of the resulting sentence.The situation is that the boy, Max was on the train and the  girl, Claire disembarked the train. The thing which is really confusing me is that there seems to be no relation between the two parts separated by the comma.

Comment: @LucyferZedd You're absolutely right to be confused (and, incidentally, if you've already buried the book in a hole in your back yard, I'd advise digging it up and driving a stake through its heart for good measure). This construction is usually used in case where A bears some kind of causal relation to B ("*The wind having become too strong, we abandoned our attempt to put up the tent*"). Are we to imagine that the indulgent driver of the train waited for the couple to complete their goodbyes before pulling on the lever? Seems unlikely in the modern world.

Comment: @LachlanDominic no not at all

Answer (score 2):

This is an absolute construction, perhaps patterned after the Latin ablative absolute.  It's pretty strange sounding for contemporary English.

> They having called their goodbyes, the train pulled out of the station.

It's improved if the "they" subject of "call" can be removed and left understood:

> Having called their goodbyes, they pulled out of the station on the train.

Comment: Actually in the story, only the boy was on the train,this being "textual grammar" , I can't use "they pulled out"

Comment: "Having called their goodbyes, they watched as the boy's train pulled out of the station."  (But even this is rather old fashioned in style.)

Comment: Get a better book. The one you're using is full of mistakes, and you won't learn English well from it.